# Having error of default values in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, linker-errors

I have set target SDK 32 and in gradle-wraper.properties  distributionUrl version is gradle-7.4-bin.zip, in this case getting the error

```
build\.transforms\cafb50b311dc4addea1aa2a85f62b9a8\transformed\mobilertc\res\values\values.xml: AAPT: error: resource color/zm_v1_black_alpha40 (aka com.cricket.livelineapp:color/zm_v1_black_alpha40) not found.
```

but when decreasing gradle-wraper.propeties version near about 6 and compilesdk 30, it's working fine but in this scenario getting an error in the integrated zoom SDK request minimum compile SDK version should be 32.

Comment: Having issue in generated values.xml

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that it is unable to find a color resource "zm_v1_black_alpha40" in the XML file.
Please check if you have that resource.
And try clean and rebuild the project.
If that doesn't solve the issue you may Invalidate cashes and restart the android studio.